# Formula to apply to delete blank cells and the cell next to it for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Was wondering if someone could help me problem solve something with the attached example dataset. I have many more so trying to work out an efficient way to do this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa32ddeh4lbz8lo/Problem%20removing%20blanks%20cells%20and%20corresponding%20left%20cell.xlsx?dl=0

In the attached excel data sheet are sets of 2 columns side-by-side marked by lines (TIME and GLU). I have used conditional formatting to highlight (in red) the blank cells in each GLU columns. What I want to do (without having to go through by hand...) is remove these blank cells (i.e. delete and move that whole column upwards) AND also delete and move upwards the single 'TIME' cell immediately to the left of each of these blank cells (as illustrated for example by the green highlighted TIME cells in column A alongside column B).

Does anyone out there know how this might be achieve via code?? Would be extremely helpful!!

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub RemoveBlank()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim Column As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Column = 2

Do While Column <= LastColumn
    LastRow = sht.Range(Cells("1", Column - 1), Cells("1", Column - 1)).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Row = LastRow
    Do While Row > 1
        If sht.Range(Cells(Row, Column), Cells(Row, Column)).Value = "" Then
            'Delets the two column row with a blank GLU and moves the rest of the data up.
            sht.Range(Cells(Row, Column - 1), Cells(Row, Column)).Select
            Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
            'Do nothing
        End If
        Row = Row - 1
    Loop
    Column = Column + 2
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```